# Can an unbounded sequence have a lower bound and no upper bound (and vice versa)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been working on some real analysis homework and I have been tasked with finding an example where a sequence $(a_n)$ is unbounded, another sequence $(b_n)$ converges to zero, and $(a_nb_n)$ is not convergent. I settled on $a_n=n^2$ and $b_n=\tfrac{1}{n}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This made me think though... as even though $n^2$ diverges to infinity as $n$ increases, it has a lower bound... so is it still unbounded? I know that by definition, a bounded function is any function that is bounded both above and below, so does this mean that any function that does not fit this definition is necessarily unbounded?

Comment: Fair enough, but my question was asking if a sequence like $n^2$ would also be considered unbounded since it is not bounded both above and below.

Comment: If that is your question, then yes. A bounded sequence is bounded above and below. Thus, an unbounded sequence would be a sequence which is unbounded above OR below (note that how "and" changed to "OR")

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. My intuition was telling me that was the case, but my intuition has been wrong a lot more than it has been right in this class. +1 for the answer and the comment. Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need intuition here. Some logic rules do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a sequence $a_n$ that doesn't have a lower bound, take $a_n = (-1)^n.n^2$ and $b_n = (-1)^n/n$. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to be bounded, a function must be bounded above and below, so failing to have either bound means the function is unbounded. An equivalent definition of being bounded is that there is a finite number $M$ such that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<M$ for every $x_1,x_2$; there is some maximum separation that two values of the function can be.